# What is binary splitting?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I was trying to learn about methods to compute pi. One algorithm that I have read about is binary splitting. It is used to compute the Chudnovsky series quicker.

https://www.ginac.de/CLN/binsplit.pdf

I have no idea what it means.

I hope someone can explain it, or pinpoint resources for me to read it up.

> Is binary splitting is applicable for all infinite series?

The paper claimed that it is applicable for all linearly convergent of a certain form (I somehow can’t type math latex here the $$ doesn’t work. The form is in the pdf) However, the examples under the “applications” section does not conform with that form.

Comment: Could you please clarify what part are you struggling with and what are your issues? The paper seems rather clear to me and contains examples both of implementation and applications.

Comment: Sorry. I made my question more explicit